# Using cython to early type class attributes

Tags: python, class, cython

I'm writing a python class and I would like to accelerate the execution using cython early typing.
I get the error `"Syntax error in C variable declaration"` when I try to cython compile the following:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

class MyClass:
    def __init__( self, np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] Redges ):
        self.Redges = Redges
        cdef double self.var1
```

The error concerns the syntax of the last line involving `self.var1`.  Am I not allowed to type class attributes directly?  Do I always have to break this up into two steps such as,

```
cdef double var1
self.var1 = var1
```

The full error traceback is,

```
test.pyx:7:24:  
Syntax error in C variable declaration  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "setup.py", line 9, in <module>  
        ext_modules = cythonize('test.pyx'), # accepts a glob pattern  
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 713, in cythonize
        cythonize_one(*args[1:])  
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 780, in cythonize_one  
        raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)  
  Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: calc_iliev_sphere.pyx
```

Comment: That's not the *full* traceback.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you want is to define an [*extension* type](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/extension_types.html). In particular your code should look like:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef class MyClass:
    cdef double var1
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] Redges

    def __init__( self, np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] Redges ):
        self.Redges = Redges
```

Note that you *cannot* impose the type of instance attributes in a normal `class`, because python allow people to change them and their types. If you try to put a `cdef` at class level in a normal python class you'll receive a compiler error by Cython.

---

Compiling the above code raises the following error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------                       
...                                                                                
import numpy as np                                                                 
cimport numpy as np                                                                

cdef class MyClass:                                                                
    cdef double var1                                                               
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] Redges                                         
                                   ^                                               
------------------------------------------------------------                       

test_cython.pyx:6:36: Buffer types only allowed as function local variables
```

Now, this is **not** a syntax error. The syntax is fine. The problem is that you simply **cannot** have an instance attribute with `np.ndarray` as type. It is a limitation of cython. In fact if you comment the `cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] Redges` line the file is compiled correctly:

Code:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef class MyClass:
    cdef double var1
    #cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] Redges

    def __init__( self, np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] Redges ):
        self.Redges = Redges
```

Output:

```
$cython test_cython.pyx 
$
```

Note: no output from `cython` which means the file was compiled succesfully.

this limitation is explained in the documentation I linked above, at the section [Attributes](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/extension_types.html#attributes):

> Attributes of an extension type are *stored directly in the object’s C
>   `struct`*. [omissis]
>
> **Note**: *You can only expose simple C types*, such as ints, floats, and strings, for Python access. You can also expose Python-valued
>   attributes.

The fact that you can only expose *simple* C data-types is because the attributes are members of the `struct`. Allowing a buffer like an `np.ndarray` would require to have variable size `struct`s.

If you want an instance attribute of type `np.ndarray` the best you can do is to define an attribute with a generic type of `object` and assign the array to it:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef class MyClass:
    cdef double var1
    cdef object Redges

    def __init__( self, np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] Redges ):
        self.Redges = Redges
```

However now everytime you access `self.Redges` you lose the speed up of cython. If you access it many times you can assign it to a local variable with the correct type.
Here's what I mean:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef class MyClass:
    cdef double var1
    cdef object Redges

    def __init__( self, np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] Redges ):
        self.Redges = Redges

    def do_stuff(self):
        cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] ar
        ar = self.Redges
        ar[0] += 1
        return ar[0]
```

In this way inside the `do_stuff` function you can have all the speed of cython using `ar`.

Comment: that solution produces another error message, I've added it to the post.

Comment: It's worth noting that the memoryview syntax (`double[:]`) doesn't have the need to keep casting between `object` and its real type, so should be much faster.

Comment: This is a confusing answer, it does not have anything to do with array having variable length. I can have my own cpp class (that is created on the stack) but not buffer, but this is not the reason, do not know what it is though :)

Comment: I've yet to get a response on a [Cython question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41926482/cython-compileerror-when-attempting-to-compile-extension-type) regarding a compile error. You may be able to help.

Comment: The cited Cython reference appears to come from an [older Pyrex documentation](https://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python/Pyrex/version/Doc/Manual/extension_types.html#ExtTypeAttrs): "Note that you can only expose simple C types, such as ints, floats and strings, for Python access. You can also expose Python-valued attributes, although read-write exposure is only possible for generic Python attributes (of type `object`). If the attribute is declared to be of an extension type, it must be exposed readonly."

Comment: @YiboYang The answer i 4 years old. The content of the site linked might have changed, however it was a cython documentation, not a pyrex one. Cython probably copy&pasted part of the original pyrex documentation when it was relevant.

Answer (score 3):

The answer of @bakuriu is quite good, I'd like to add how this can be done with keeping a memory view as a class member:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef class MyClass:
    cdef public double var1
    cdef public np.float64_t[:] Redges

    def __init__( self, np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] Redges ):
        self.Redges = Redges
```

With that approach `do_stuff` gets simpler:

```
def do_stuff(self):
    # With using buffer protocol, this just wraps the memory view
    # with numpy object without copying data
    np_redges = np.asarray(self.Redges)

    # Now you have np_redges, a numpy object. Even though, it's not a pure 
    # C array, it allows calling numpy functions with all the power of MKL, e.g.:
    np.add(np_redges, 1.0, np_redges)
```